# ASP.NET Core Web API. Process finished with exit code 500

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, логирование

В качестве IDE использую Rider. После того, как я закрываю приложение, в консоль пишется `Process finished with exit code 500`, но не всегда, иногда приложение завершается с кодом 0. Из-за чего это могло произойти? Или как выяснить, почему так произошло, где найти логи по этой ошибке?

Comment: Краш незавершенных асинхронных операций, необработанные исключения.

Comment: Тоже подумал на асинхронность. Вот только пока даже предположить не могу, почему это происходит. Я только начал разработку приложения и у меня там буквально 2-3 асинхронных метода, которые успешно завершаются в рамках запроса

Answer (score 0):

Похоже, дело не в моём приложении, а в Rider. Вместе с ним идёт DPA (Dynamic Program Analysis). Я его отключил и пока не получал 500 код ошибки. Но мне нужно ещё проверить, обновлю ответ, если всё же получу ошибку даже с выключенным DPA